# Double versioning generated by edit a listitem

Tags: 2013, versioning, update

I have many lists (with versioning enabled) with different scenarios by saving an item from edit mode:

1. Without changing anything -> no version is created
2. Without changing anything -> 1 new empty version is created
3. Without changing anything -> 2 new empty versions are created
4. Changing something -> 1 new version is created
5. Changing something -> 1 new AND 1 empty version are created

Of corse 1,2 and 3 refer to different lists, as 4 and 5.
4 is always related to 1.
5 to 2 and 3.

There are NO `workflows` or `javascripts` which could be the problem.

How it is possible that there are this differences by different lists?

Answer (score 0):

1 - is a list **without** versions.2

2 and 4 - is a list **with** versions.
when click 'save', a new version created. even if you don't change anything!

but, I don't now when two versions created (3 and 5)

Comment: Actually, my scenarios refer only to lists with versioning enabled.